# tf lookupTransform sigabrt

Tags: c++, transforms, tf2, transform-listener, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

i want to get the transformation between my /map and /robot_0/base_link. I am currentry trying it with:

```
tf::TransformListener listener;
    tf::StampedTransform transform;
    listener.lookupTransform("/map",
                             "/robot_0/base_link",
                             ros::Time(0),
                             transform);
```

but i always get a SIGABRT.
What I am doing wrong ?
my tf tree: [image: image description]

regards,

Edit:
i get the following Error message:
[image: image description]
Peter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146026/tf-lookuptransform-sigabrt/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2014-03-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any output? (Do you have `output="screen"` in your launch file?)

It would help if you could post the full code for the node. Are you catching the exceptions mentioned in the API? http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Transformer.html#ac01a9f8709a828c427f1a5faa0ced42b

**Edit:**

It looks like your are trying to look up a transform before the listener has received enough information. Try adding a call to `waitForTransform` before `lookupTransform`. If that doesn't help, please add more of your code to your question.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2014-04-02**:
i solved the problem, i had to use ros::Time::now() instead of ros::Time(0). I do not know why the code fom http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29 does not work, maybe there is something wrong in the tutorial example code.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-02**:
I have no idea why it would work with ros::Time::now() and not ros::Time(0). In any case it would be a good idea to explictely add a call to waitForTransform. Your code is likely brittle to timeing changes. If your problem is solved, please inicate that by marking an answer as accepted. Thanks.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-04-02**:
There are also no try/catch blocks. Even with waitForTransform there might still be an exception.